# Macaulay2 error: expected a $0$-dimensional system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, numerical-methods, macaulay2

What does the error `stdio:28:6:(3): error: expected a 0-dimensional system` mean and how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Below is the code:

```
needsPackage "NumericalAlgebraicGeometry"
NumericalAlgebraicGeometry
Package
R = QQ[sa,sb,sc,sd,se,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce]
system = {-cb sa - cd sa - ce sa + ca sb + ca sd + ca se, 
 cb sa - ca sb - cc sb - cd sb - ce sb + cb sc + cb sd + cb se, 
 cc sb - cb sc - cd sc - ce sc + cc sd + cc se, 
 cd sa + cd sb + cd sc - ca sd - cb sd - cc sd - ce sd + cd se, 
 ce sa + ce sb + ce sc + ce sd - ca se - cb se - cc se - cd se, -1 + 
  ca^2 + sa^2, -1 + cb^2 + sb^2, -1 + cc^2 + sc^2, -1 + cd^2 + sd^2}
```

Comment: It seems to me this is not a mathematics question.

Comment: Do you care about just getting a single solution or do you need them all? If you impose an extra equation, and it works out to give a 0-dimensional solution set, will that be okay?

Comment: @AHusain I would need all of the solutions, and I don't have extra equations to be inserted. Does the error mean the polynomial equation is positive-dim? If yes, maybe here (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3297.pdf page 4) is the method for solving this kind of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical algebraic geometry focuses a lot on finding single "witness" solutions to a set of equations. Often the methods ask for the solution set to be only a finite set of points. This is called a "0-dimensional" system. If the solution set is a finite set of curves it is 1-dimensional, a finite set of surfaces is 2-dimensional, and so on.

So when the package tells you your system is not 0-dimensional it means there are infinitely many solutions and you need more equations for the algorithms to work. As a rule, you need at least as many equations as you have variables. You have 9 equations and 10 variables which one expects will form a 1-dimensional solution set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! May I ask: (1) 'If the solution set is a finite set of curves it is 1-dimensional, a finite set of surfaces is 2-dimensional, and so on.' where can I find the source of this statement? and does the dimension specifically refer to the dimension of the ideal formed by polynomials? (2) so the polynomial equations post here is positive-dim system, does this indicate that I need to find algorithms for solving positive-dim system? Maybe here  ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3297.pdf page 4) is the method? Thank you again!

Comment: @HJ_dynamics That's what dimension means. A curve is defined to be 1-dimensional just as 1-dimensional is defined to be a curve. They go hand in hand. In algebraic geometry, you sometimes find that your solution set is not a single curve however, but a union of what are called "irreducible components". I would recommend you read about dimension and irreducible varieties in a textbook on algebraic geometry (possibly one that doesn't use the language of schemes would be most appropriate).

Comment: Secondly, yes, there are algorithms that find "witness sets" for irreducible components if you have a positive dimensional system. It's not my area so I don't know what all the resources there are for learning about this but here's one https://www3.nd.edu/~cwample1/Preprints/intro2AlgGeom.pdf (section 4).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Following the question 1, I just tried the code ```I1= ideal {-cb*sa - ce*sa + ca*sb + ca*se, 
 cb*sa - ca*sb - cc*sb - ce*sb + cb*sc + cb*se, 
 cc*sb - cb*sc - cd*sc + cc*sd, cd*sc - cc*sd, 
 ce*sa + ce*sb - ca*se - cb*se, -1 + ca^2 + sa^2, -1 + cb^2 + 
  sb^2, -1 + cc^2 + sc^2, -1 + cd^2 + sd^2, -1 + ce^2 + se^2}``` ```dim I1``` for computing a polynomial equations, it gives dimension 1, however according to the solutions found by Mathematica (in Macaulay2, should obtain the same result), the solutions are isolated points instead of a finite number of curves.

Comment: continue the above: Am I misunderstanding the concepts of *dimension of ideal* and *dimension of solutions*?

Comment: @HJ_dynamics I trust Macaulay more than Mathematica when it comes to algebraic geometry. The dimension of an ideal $I$ is defined as the dimension of the ring $R/I$ which happens to coincide with the dimension of the solution set $V(I)$. Singular also confirms the dimension is 1. Also I can count and I count 9 equations and 10 variables so I know there's no way it's a finite set of solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134338/discussion-between-hj-dynamics-and-trevor-gunn).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the continued confusion, but when I type in ```s = solveSystem f```, Macaulay2 gives finite solutions, and does not report the error ```error: expected a 0-dimensional system```. It seems that the system is 0-dim..

Comment: it happened the same for the ideal ```I = ideal {-cb*sa - cc*sa + ca*sb + ca*sc, cb*sa - ca*sb - cc*sb + cb*sc, 
 cc*sa + cc*sb - ca*sc - cb*sc, -1 + ca^2 + sa^2, -1 + cb^2 + 
  sb^2, -1 + cc^2 + sc^2}```, which actually has finite zeros, but Macaylay2 code ```dim(R/I)``` gives 5.